# T-SQL - Querying Hierarchical Table with Running Subtotal (each row has an item count)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I'm trying to create a dynamic navigation based off of a hierarchical table which follows this design:

> CREATE TABLE #CPTree (UID int, ParentID int, Name nvarchar(150),
>   ItemCount int)
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree VALUES ('1' , '0', 'Vehicles', '0')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree VALUES ('2' , '1', 'Bikes', '10')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree VALUES ('3' , '1', 'Cars', '20')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree Values ('5' , '2', 'Bike Make 1', '0')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree Values ('6' , '2', 'Bike Make 2', '5')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree Values ('7' , '3', 'Car Make 1', '0')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree Values ('8' , '3', 'Car Make 2', '0')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree Values ('9' , '5', 'Bike Model A', '7')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree Values ('10' , '5', 'Bike Model B', '1')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree Values ('11' , '7', 'Car Model D', '4')
>
> INSERT INTO #CPTree Values ('12' , '8', 'Car Model X', '2')
>
> --Retrieve level of category/child categories with CTE
>
> ;with HCTE(CategoryID, ParentID, Name, itemcount, Level) as ( select
>   UID, ParentID, Name, itemcount, 0 as Level from #CPTree c where c.UID
>   = 3 -- Cars Category
>
> union all select c.UID, c.ParentID, c.Name, c.itemcount, ch.Level + 1
>   from #CPTree c inner join HCTE ch on ch.CategoryID = c.ParentID )
>
> SELECT * FROM HCTE
>
> DROP TABLE #CPTree
>
> --end

I would like to retrieve the total item count for each category, for example the Top level category 'Cars' (item count 20) has 2 children (0 item count for both), and each of those have children (2 and 4 item count respectfully). The total item count for Cars would be 26.  Likewise, the total item count for Car Make 1 (CategoryID 7) would be 4 (sum from it's child - CategoryID 11).  The result would return this:

> CategoryID | ParentID | Name       | ItemCount | Level |
>   TotalItemCount
>
> 3 |     1   |      Cars  |       20      |      0  |     26
>
> 7  |     3    |         Car Make 1 |   0   |         1   |     4
>
> 8 |      3    |         Car Make 2  |  0  |          1   |     2
>
> 12     |     8    |         Car Model X |  2    |        2   |     2
>
> 11     |     7        |     Car Model D  4    |          2   |     4

This would allow me to see if subcategories had any items within their subcategories, but not necessarily if they had any items themselves. My live table has many levels, so the query would have to continue to drill through the categories until it hit the last level.  I can provide a deeper example if necessary.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea used is to add a trail of ancestors (as a string) for each node in the tree, then to sum up all rows that have that node in it.

```
   ;with HCTE(CategoryID, ParentID, Name, itemcount, Level, trail)
    as
    (
     select UID, ParentID, Name, itemcount, 0 as Level, 
                                                  '/' + cast(UID as varchar(max))+ '/' as trail 
     from #CPTree c
     where c.UID = 3 -- Cars Category


union all

select c.UID, c.ParentID, c.Name, c.itemcount, ch.Level + 1, 
                                               trail + CAST(UID as varchar(max)) + '/'
from #CPTree c 
inner join HCTE ch on ch.CategoryID = c.ParentID
)
select CategoryID, ParentID, Name, ItemCount,
   (select SUM(ItemCount)
    from HCTE h2
    where charindex('/' + CAST(h1.CategoryID as varchar(max)) + '/', h2.trail, 1) <> 0
   )
 from hcte h1
```

Answer (score 0):

In your simple example, replace your select statement with the select below.

SELECT *, (select COUNT(*) from HCTE b where a.Level+1 = b.Level ) Children  FROM HCTE a

Its very simple, but if you have lots and lots of levels then it wont scale very well.

But you can reference the CTE multiple times in the select statement.

Comment: thanks MarkPm, that will give me count of children for each category, but I need to sum the itemcount for each category to it's parent.  I can do something like this: SELECT *, (select sum(itemcount) from HCTE b where a.Level+1 = b.Level and a.CategoryId = B.ParentId) as TotalItemCount FROM HCTE a, but it won't sum up to the top level category

Answer (score 0):

I know you've accepted an answer but I would seriously look at [this technique](http://www.rkimball.com/html/designtipsPDF/DesignTips2001/KimballDT17Populating.pdf) from the DWH world.

The query you've accepted has 5 from clauses, and depending on how/if the optimizer materializes the HCTE, you'll be reading and joining the same table a few times over.

The technique essentially builds a "hierarchical index". Like every other index you'll spend time on insert/update/delete to save time at query. And like every other index you spend a little space too.

In the end you have an extremely fast way to get to the exact answers you want.

Depending on your needs the "index" can be maintained via trigger if updates to the car make and model table are frequent and unscheduled. Or if you load that table once a day you can just rebuild the "index" with a single statement.

Comment: Thanks Stephanie, I'll take a look